# C Compilation error on mac

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors

```
gcc -c -o fsbench.o fsbench.c -O3 -Wall -Wextra
gcc -o fsbench fsbench.o -O3 -Wall -Wextra -lpthread
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_reposition_offset", referenced from:
  _perf_io in fsbench.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     invocation)
make: *** [fsbench] Error 1
```

I am not able to compile my program on mac. It keeps throwing this error. I tried several things and was not able to compile it without error.

Comment: The object that supplies the reposition_offset() function has not been supplied as input ld.  Go find the object file that function lives it, and pass it as an argument to gcc.  You probably won't get a better answer than this unless someone else has specific experience with the program you're trying to compile.  Read up on compiling programs with gcc and linking in shared libraries and/or object files.

Comment: BTW, even though you invoke `gcc`, you are using `clang`, which is symlinked to `gcc` on recent Macs.